# Bootstrap: Background image z-index to show it above bg color

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

See pen [here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MKovPb)

I've to code this image [image]

this is what i'm doing

```
   <div class="container-fluid"  id="contactbg">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12" id="info">
                <h1 >Get More Information</h1>
                <h2>on our educational and training programs </h2>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="pos">
          <div class="row" id="contact">
            <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-4  col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
                       form here 
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

here is css

```
#contact {
    background:#0072d5;//blue 
    padding: 20px ;  
}
#contact .form-control{
    background: transparent;
    border-radius: 4px; 
    border-color: #fff;

}
#pos{position: relative;}
#contactbg{
    position: relative;        
    background: url(../images/contact-bg.png) no-repeat ;
    background-position: right center;
    z-index: 99999999 !important;
}
```

now this is what i get as output

[image]

how to  fix this pleas help

Comment: Can you create a simple fidlle?

Comment: add position absolute to get the image above the blue container like this: #contactbg{
    position: absolute;        
    background: url(../images/contact-bg.png) no-repeat ;
    background-position: right center;
    z-index: 99999999 !important;
}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go: [codepen.io](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GoEvLa?editors=110). You just need replace classes `contact` and `contactbg`. And cut man on image separately with no background to another div with `position:absolute`.

Answer (score 0):

The `position:relative` needs to be changed to `position:absolute`

Like so:

```
#contactbg
{ 
    position: absolute; 
    background: url(../images/contact-bg.png) no-repeat ; 
    background-position: right center; 
    z-index: 99999999 !important; 
}
```

Hope this helps!